Power Automate - Read from excel [no table present] and send alert with specific value - Range of dynamic excelsheet
I'm trying to find a solution but I really get stuck with the following:
I have an excel file that looks like this:
Test.xlsx

It's on "Sheet1". This file is generated via Power Automate, it renews every morning. The file is on a Sharepoint Folder. The number of rows can very a lot over time. The columns will stay the same over time.
My desired outcome is that via Power automate, every morning at 8AM is checks this file to see if any of the "List" values (this is unique) a value of 100% in the "Def" column is present. And if so, an email is sent to someone with the "List" value and a message.
I tried many things, and the part where I get stuck is how I get the actual row data of the excel into my power automate flow. My excel does not contain a table (and it is not possible to add this). So I tried different combinations with:

"get file content using path" (sharepoint)
"create table"
"List rows present in a table"

with the above I get the error:
Action 'Create_table' failed: Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Create_table' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'range' expects two integer parameters: an inclusive start index of the range as the first parameter and a count of integers to return as the second parameter. The function was invoked with '0' parameter(s). Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#range for usage details.'.
I also read somewhere that I could use "Parse JSON", finding out the schema via "Compose". But I also think that I don't always understand how I transfer an output to the next step as an input, so maybe someone could help me with really specific things that I should put in. Also with the "range" error, to be honest, as much as I read about it, I keep missing what information I should put in (when this is about a variable data sheet, and when I see question How to get the content of an Excel sheet from OneDrive using Power Automate I still don't get the range with a variable table size), it looks like this:

Hope this is enought information
